# Zurb foundation SASS section include mixin

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use the Section Mixin from Zurb Foundation

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/section.html

As i see in the source:

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_section.scss

I can call the section mixin as:

```
.section-container {
    @include section-container($section-type:accordion);
    & > section { @include section($section-type:accordion, $title-selector:".title-sample", $content-selector:".content-sample"); }
  }
```

Which results with the following error:

```
Mixin section doesn't have the following arguments: $title_selector, $content_selector.
```

I have tried using just the include and that works without parameters. but i want to customize the colors and all the properties there.

Can you give me some pointers.

i am using a Rails app with the SASS gem, Compass and Zurb foundation gems installed and set-up.

Comment: Can you show the section Mixin code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that i had to update zurb. i was using 4.0.9. and these mixin options seems were added afterwards.